# How to generate time limited QR Code in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am implementing a QR-Code Generator in Swift, that generates a QR-Code from text, it is pretty simple to do, but i also want, that the generated QR-Code will be active only for some specific amount of time, for example after 1 Week the QR-Code should not be scanable or deactivated/should not work. I searched a lot but couldn't find any answer to this question.

**Is it actually possible to generate time-limited QR-Codes in Swift?**

So my code, that generates a QR-Code looks like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
var filter: CIFilter!

@IBAction func generateCodePressed(_ sender: UIButton){
      if let text = myTextField.text {
         let data = text.data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)
         filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
         filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
         let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
         myImageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: filter.outputImage!.transformed(by: transform))
      }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no way to make it not “scannable”. What you can do is to  include an expiration date in its data and use it when it is decoded.

Comment: Btw for security reasons you should encrypt the data sent in your QRCode

Comment: Oh, that's a great idea, I didn't think about that, thank you many many times!

Comment: Another option is to have something like an UUID in your QRCode and the backend validate its expiration

Comment: I think for my case the idea with encryption is more suitable, thanks a lot!